# Why doesn't python's griddata produce identical results to MATLAB's scatteredInterpolant, and is there a python package which is identical?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, interpolation

I am attempting to translate a bit of MATLAB code into python that involves three-dimensional interpolation. My understanding is that the underlying mechanisms behind MATLAB's scatteredInterpolant and python's griddata subpackage (from scipy.interpolate) are the same (both involve Delaunay triangulation of data in a grid followed by linear interpolation). However, when I test identical data using both scatteredInterpolant and griddata, I get different results for some of the estimates (some are identical). I believe this to be because Delaunay triangulation is not unique and can have several valid solutions. However, for what I am doing I need an identical result. Can anyone advise me on how to address this or whether a different python package might work better? I have investigated a few other methods in python but haven't found anything even close to what I need.

MATLAB code:

```matlab
%MATLAB code on some made up data (real data behaves similarly):

depth = [10;2;0;2;1;0;0;10;1;1.1;7.5;7;9;9.9;8;5];
lat = [5;5;0;0;4;2.7;0;0;10;6;3;4.4;3.3;2;9;9];
lon = [0;0;8;4;3;2.5;0;10;5;4.4;7;9.9;1;6.5;8;7];

C_grid = [99;87;88;89;78;79;65;67;75;75;75;75;75;75;75;75];

lat_grid = [0;0;0;0;10;10;10;10;-50;-50;-50;-50;50;50;50;50];
lon_grid = [0;10;0;10;0;10;0;10;-50;50;-50;50;-50;50;-50;50];
depth_grid = [0;0,;10;10;0;0;10;10;-50;-50;50;50;-50;-50;50;50];

interp = scatteredInterpolant(lon_grid, lat_grid, depth_grid, C_grid);
interpolation = interp(lon, lat, depth);

%RESULT: 76.5, 86.3, 89.4, 92.0, 85.9, 90.3, 99.0, 89.0, 77.2, 80.2, 81.3, 82.9, 80.3, 84.0, 71.2, 74.6
```

Python code on the same data:

```py
import numpy as np

depth = np.array((10, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 10, 1, 1.1, 7.5, 7, 9, 9.9, 8, 5))
lat = np.array((5,5, 0, 0, 4, 2.7, 0, 0, 10, 6, 3, 4.4, 3.3, 2, 9, 9))
lon = np.array((0, 0, 8, 4, 3, 2.5, 0, 10, 5, 4.4, 7, 9.9, 1, 6.5, 8, 7))

lat_grid = np.array((0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,-50,-50,-50,-50,50,50,50,50))
lon_grid = np.array((0,10,0,10,0,10,0,10,50,50,-50,50,-50,50,-50,50))
depth_grid = np.array((0,0,10,10,0,0,10,10,-50,-50,50,50,-50,-50,50,50))
C_grid = np.array((99,87,88,89,78,79,65,67,75,75,75,75,75,75,75,75))

points = (lon_grid, lat_grid, depth_grid)
values = C_grid
xi = (lon, lat, depth)

import scipy
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

interpolation = griddata(points, values, xi, method="linear")
print(interpolation)

#RESULT: 76.5, 86.3, 89.4, 92.0, 87.1, 90.3, 99.0, 89.0, 77.3, 81.23, 81.6, 78.7, 81.9, 84.2, 71.3, 73.5
```

1. Why are some results different between the two methods?
2. Is there a python method that will exactly replicate the MATLAB scatteredInterpolant?

Comment: The differences may be due to slight numeric differences.  I used the MATLAB triangulation years ago for FEM work, but don't know how sensitive it is.  Best stick with well scaled point layout to avoid distorted  or other oddly shaped triangles..  I assume they use the same compiled package, but versions could differ.  The original is more than 20 years old.  Scip/numpy is the most  used python pairing for these purposes.But you could search pypi for less known packages.

Comment: Without a specific difference example and code, this is just a banned 'recommendation' question.

Comment: If the differences are indeed caused by a different Delaunay solution, which happens when four points form a square that can be split in two equivalent ways, then adding a bit of noise to your coordinates would solve that, leaving only a single solution.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations. For what I need, the grid is already pre-determined and I have gone through the scipy/numpy packages already, but I didn't think to try pypi. Additionally, I will look into adding some noise, as recommended. There should be some example code with the question now (was temporarily a formatting issue as I am new to this forum), please let me know if you have further ideas given the example code that is shown.